# How can I dynamically use an Eloquent model, and call the eloquent functions on a variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Users should be able to click the "knives" link and get a table displaying data about knives. Or click Backpacks and get a table of data on backpacks.

I'm able to pass the "knives" variable to the main/knives/ page as $id, however when I try and get the model with

use \App\Models$id

I get the error that App\Models"Knives" cannot be found. (Parenthesis stick)

use \App\Models\knives does work.

I get a similar issue when I try to do $id::get or $id::all, I must write it manually as knives::all.

**How can I get these parentheses out of the way? should I approach this differently? How can I dynamically get this model**

[Red arrows indicate where I'd like variables, blue indicates where variables work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3lE7.png)

Comment: "use" is a PHP keyword, so it must be followed with a space after

Comment: @EmekaOkafor That typo is not present in the code. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but you can call methods on classes dynamically like this (not tested):

```
    $namespace = "\\App\\Models\\";
    $modelName = "knives";

    $result = ($namespace . $modelName)::all();
   
    // Or alternatively:
    $result = (new ($namespace . $modelName))->get();

    // Or even with dynamic methods
    $method = "find";

    $result = ($namespace . $modelName)::$method(10);
```

I don't think you can use variables inside `use` statements in PHP (or at least not that I'm aware of).

Comment: This worked! Thank you very kindly. Appreciate the options and rephrasing of my question as "call methods on classes dynamically" seems accurate.

Comment: You give a mouse a cookie and, hey you wouldn't have any ideas on how to make my use statements dynamic would you?

Comment: I dont think programming languages support dynamic imports in general. I don't think its good practise too. Is there a specific reason why you need it? Can't you solve the problem using polymorphism or simply by adding an `entity_type` to your database column where you store a specific namespace?